# Unable to close file, being used by another process

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, process

I am trying to find a way to close the process that is holding the pdf file that I am creating. I have tried to dispose and close the stream after it is created but I get the message that The process cannot access the file '\server\PDFs\test.pdf' because it is being used by another process. Basically once test.pdf is created originally I then have a page where they can edit the data and it recreates a revised test.pdf. Any idea how I can close the process? I tried doing a while statement loop to keep trying but no luck?

```
'Create the original pdf
 Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(path & myUniqueFileName, FileMode.Create))

    Doc1.Open()
    Dim test As String
    test = Session("PDF")
    Dim PDFHeader As String
    PDFHeader = Session("Header")
    Dim imagepath As String = Server.MapPath(".") & "/images/Header.png"
    Dim image As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath)
    image.ScalePercent(70.0F)
    Dim line1 As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator(0.0F, 100.0F, BaseColor.BLACK, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1)

    Doc1.Add(image)
    Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(PDFHeader))
    Doc1.Add(New Chunk(line1))
    Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(test))
    pdfWrite.Flush()
    Doc1.Close()
    Doc1.Dispose()
    pdfWrite.Dispose()
    pdfWrite.Close()
```

Re-create the pdf after editing the data:

```
 Dim _fileInUse As Boolean = True
    Do While _fileInUse
        _fileInUse = FileInUse(myUniqueFileName)
        If Not _fileInUse Then
            Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(path & myUniqueFileName, FileMode.Create))


            Doc1.Open()
            Dim test As String
            test = Session("PDF")
            Dim PDFHeader As String
            PDFHeader = Session("Header")
            Dim imagepath As String = Server.MapPath(".") & "/images/Header.png"
            Dim image As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath)
            image.ScalePercent(70.0F)
            Dim line1 As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator(0.0F, 100.0F, BaseColor.BLACK, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1)

            Doc1.Add(image)
            Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(PDFHeader))
            Doc1.Add(New Chunk(line1))
            Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(test))
        End If
    Loop



    Doc1.Close()
    Doc1.Dispose()

Public Function FileInUse(ByVal sFile As String) As Boolean

    Dim thisFileInUse As Boolean = False
    Dim fs As FileStream

    If File.Exists(sFile) Then
        Try
            fs = File.Open(sFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)

            fs.Close()
            fs.Dispose()
        Catch
            Try
                fs.Close()
                fs.Dispose()
            Catch

            End Try

            thisFileInUse = True
        End Try
    End If
    Return thisFileInUse
End Function
```

Comment: You can't overwrite the file but you do have the option to rename the old file and then write the new one.

Comment: How would I go about renaming the old file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a `New FileStream` in `Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter =...` with no way to close it.

I suggest that you use the Using construct to take care of disposing of things for you, and also take advantage of the Finally clause in a Try..Catch, like this:

```
Sub X()
    'Create the original pdf
    Using doc1 As New Document
        Dim myFile As String = Path.Combine(myPath, myUniqueFileName)
        Using fs As New FileStream(myFile, FileMode.Create)
            Using pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, fs)

                doc1.Open()
                Dim test As String
                test = Session("PDF")
                Dim PDFHeader As String
                PDFHeader = Session("Header")
                Dim imagepath As String = Server.MapPath("./images/Header.png")
                Dim image As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath)
                image.ScalePercent(70.0F)
                Dim line1 As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator(0.0F, 100.0F, BaseColor.BLACK, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1)

                doc1.Add(image)
                doc1.Add(New Paragraph(PDFHeader))
                doc1.Add(New Chunk(line1))
                doc1.Add(New Paragraph(test))
                pdfWrite.Flush()

            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub

Public Function FileInUse(ByVal sFile As String) As Boolean

    Dim thisFileInUse As Boolean = False

    If File.Exists(sFile) Then
        Dim fs As FileStream = Nothing
        Try
            fs = File.Open(sFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
        Catch
            thisFileInUse = True
        Finally
            If fs IsNot Nothing Then
                fs.Dispose()
            End If
        End Try
    End If

    Return thisFileInUse

End Function
```

The Finally part of a Try..Catch always runs.

**Edit:** You will of course have checked that the .Dispose() method on an instance of a Class will take care of any housework which needs to be done, for example I checked [Stream.Dispose Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227422.aspx) before not doing an explicit .Close(). I don't have documentation to hand for the methods of ITextSharp, so you'll have to check that for yourself.

Comment: I tried "USING" like in your example and still the same error. I am not sure how I am supposed to use the dispose() methode. I am doing a pdfwrite.dispose

Comment: @user1342164 1) Did you use Using for the StreamWriter too? 2) The End Using calls .Dispose() on whatever its corresponding Using declared.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just create another file with a unique name and update that. I haven't tried it but I don't like the idea of continually trying to open the file in a loop to check if you can write to it or not. Maybe that's causing issues in itself

Something like this?:

```
'Create the original pdf
Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(path &          myUniqueFileName, FileMode.Create))
Dim rdm As New Random()
Dim newName As String
newName =  myUniqueFileName + rdm.Next(0, 100000).ToString("00000")

Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(path & newName , FileMode.Create))
Doc1.Open()
Dim test As String
test = Session("PDF")
Dim PDFHeader As String
PDFHeader = Session("Header")
Dim imagepath As String = Server.MapPath(".") & "/images/Header.png"
Dim image As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath)
        image.ScalePercent(70.0F)
Dim line1 As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator(0.0F, 100.0F, BaseColor.BLACK, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1)

Doc1.Add(image)
Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(PDFHeader))
Doc1.Add(New Chunk(line1))
Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(test))

Doc1.Close()
Doc1.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this as well and mark as answer after I finish